# Route 53 site doesn't work unless www is present

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have migrated my domains from another provider to Route53.

Everything is working OK except when I try to navigate to my website without the www's. I get a DNS error. I'm sure it's something elementary I've missed (Extra alias, cname entry etc.)

For clarity's sake - www.domain.com works and domain.com does not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing an `A` record for the route.